# Ruby script to prompt for password and have user enter password again for verification

Tags: ruby

I've written a ruby script that asks for a password and assigns it to a variable for user later on. I would like to be able to ask the user for the password again for verification.

Here's what I have now, I'm just not sure how to ask for the password again in order to verify.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
#
require 'rubygems'
require 'highline/import'

def getPassword(prompt)
  loop do
    word = ask("#{prompt}") { |x| x.echo = "*" }
    if word.nil? or word.empty?
     puts 'Password cannot be blank.'
    else
     return word
     break
    end
  end
end

user_password = getPassword('Enter User Password')
```

Comment: Can you not call `getPassword` again and assign the result in a new var, e.g. `second_user_password = getPassword('Enter User Password Again')`

Comment: and then something like `puts "WRONG!" unless second_user_password  == user_password `  ?

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I ask the password again?"?. You already did it once, what's the problem with doing it twice? Try to be more explicit in your question please ^^

Comment: Sorry guys, it's Monday after a long weekend. Kris, you're right. I added another variable asking for getPassword and comparing them. Thanks!

Comment: You are no longer checking for empty passwords just FYI

Comment: Thansk raph! I just added checking for that again.

Comment: There is no point using `break` after you `return word`. Ruby will never see `break`.

Comment: Thanks Tin Man, good point.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have changed:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
#
require 'rubygems'
require 'highline/import'

def getPassword(prompt)
  loop do
    word = ask("#{prompt}") { |x| x.echo =  "*" }
    verify = ask("#{prompt} Again") { |z| z.echo =  "*" }
     if word != verify
       puts "They do not match"
     else
       puts "They Match"
       return word
       break
     end
  end
end

user_password = getPassword('Enter User Password')
```